# Sorting photos to subfolers using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code to sort photos by file date to new monthly folders, but I cant.

Code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
import os

our_files = Path(r"C:\Users\dovyd\OneDrive\Desktop\testas")

for file in our_files.iterdir(): 
    if file.is_file() and file.stem != '.DS_Store':
        directory = file.parent
        extension = file.suffix
        
        old_name = file.stem
        region, report_type, old_date = old_name.split('-')
        
        old_date = datetime.strptime(old_date, '%Y%b%d')
        date = datetime.strftime(old_date, '%Y-%b-%d')
        
        new_file = f'{date} - {region}  {report_type}{extension}'
        
        month = datetime.strftime(old_date, "%B")
        new_path = our_files.joinpath(month)
        
        if not new_path.exists():
            new_path.mkdir()
            
        new_file_path = new_path.joinpath(new_file)
        
        
        file.replace(new_file_path)
```

Error:

```
File "...\AAAA.py", line 14, in <module>
    region, report_type, old_date = old_name.split('-')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Comment: At least one filename didn't have any dashes, therefore `split()` only returned one part.

Comment: I have removed the [tag:powershell] tag as the question doesn't relate to it. Re-add it if you consider this is PowerShell related.

Comment: The error indicates that your the photo file name does not have A-B-C text. Suppose, when you are trying to split `A.png`, it cannot split the name into `region, report_type, old_date` as it does not have 3 dashes `-`.

Comment: *"Im not sure what im writing, becouse i'm very new at this. Found this code in youtube, but it just wont work"* - not a good way to ask a question... You are expected to ask about **your own code** and show some minimal amount of research and a [mre]. We are not here to debug for you. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask]

Answer (score 1):

This one should work. You just need to specify `DIR_SORTED_PATH_STR`(root directory to copy your images into) and `SOURCE_DIR_PATH_STR`(the directory to copy from).
You don't have to create the directories for each year and month. It's done automatically.
If you need to move files, change `copy` to `move`

```
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy
from time import gmtime
from os.path import getmtime, join
from os import makedirs

DIR_SORTED_PATH_STR = "path/to/destination"
SOURCE_DIR_PATH_STR = "path/to/source"
dir_path = Path(SOURCE_DIR_PATH_STR)


for path in dir_path.iterdir(): 
    if path.is_file() and path.stem != '.DS_Store':
        mod_time = gmtime(getmtime(path))
        dir_path = join(DIR_SORTED_PATH_STR, str(mod_time.tm_year), str(mod_time.tm_mon))
        makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)
        new_file_path = join(dir_path, path.name)
        copy(path, new_file_path)
```

This code uses the last modification date of the file, because getting the creation date [might be difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times). If it is crucial, choose an option from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times).